# Let $\tau=\{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{I},\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}.$ Does $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ converge in this topology?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $\tau=\{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{I},\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}.$ Does $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ converge in this topology?

Given the following definition of convergence $\forall (W \in \tau, W \ni p) \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N \ p \in W$, I think the sequence converges for all positive rationals. The presences of irrationals in this topology throws me.

Comment: For typesetting: note that `$\Bbb Q$` gives you $\Bbb Q$.  This works for any other letters you want to put in blackboard bold.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko note that $\Bbb I = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$

Comment: Once again, weird undefined symbols...

Comment: And that definition of convergence is, almost surely, wrong: it should be, I think: $$a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} p\iff \forall (W\in\tau\;s.t.\;p\in W)\exists N\in\Bbb N\;s.t. :\;\forall\,n>N\;,\;\;a_n\in W$$

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Yeah, I know...in spite of everything.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko note that $\Bbb I$ stands for "irrational".  This use of the symbol is not completely unprecedented.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko: The OP may not know that there are two conventions for the symbol $\Bbb I$ and two for a standard symbol for the irrationals. In any case, the claim that $\{\Bbb Q,\Bbb I,\varnothing,\Bbb R\}$ is a topology makes it pretty clear what convention is in use here.

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of convergence (which you have mistyped), we may indeed say that $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $p$ for every $p \in \Bbb Q$.  Note that this is not true for $p \in \Bbb I = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Does the sequence converge for all the rationals, or only the positive ones?

Comment: In what way does this topology distinguish between positive and non-positive rationals?  That is, if $p,q \in \Bbb Q$ with $q\leq 0<p$, then does $p$ have any topological property that $q$ does not?

Comment: Oh, I see my error, now. Thanks!