# Let $\tau=\{\mathbb{Q,I,R},\emptyset\}$. Discuss the convergence or divergence of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ in this topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\tau=\{\mathbb{Q,I,R},\emptyset\}$. Discuss the convergence or divergence of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ in this topology.

Before anyone flags this question as a duplicate, I do realize that there is an exact question posted 3 years ago. However I'm not looking for answer so much as an explanation. Or perhaps better stated, a clarification. I believe $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ converges to $p,\forall p\in\mathbb{Q}$. I believe this is true for $\mathbb{R}$ as well but not for $\mathbb{I}$. Am I correct?

Comment: "I believe this is true for $\mathbb{R}$ as well". What is it what is true as well?

Comment: Convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: $1/n\to p$, for all $p\in\mathbb{Q}$, because the neighborhoods of $p$ are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and both contain all elements of the sequence.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is the entire space. Convergence is being considered in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the topology $\tau$).

Comment: So because $\mathbb{I}$ does not contain any elements of the sequence therefore it doesn't converge in $\mathbb{I}$ correct?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why it doesn't converge in $\mathbb{I}$?

Comment: The sequence doesn't converge **to** any point $p\in\mathbb{I}$, because such a point has a neighborhood that doesn't contain infinitely many points of the sequence. That neighborhood is $\mathbb{I}$, which in fat doesn't contain any point of the sequence.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks!

Comment: The [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1045993/4280)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use $\mathbb{P}$ for the irrational numbers, as is common in topology.

So $\tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{P},\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}\}$, and it's easy to check this is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. To check convergence we recall the definition: $a_n \to x$ iff for all open sets $O$ such that $x \in O$, $O$ contains all but finitely many points $a_n$.

The key observation is that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ any open $O$ that contains $x$ is either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, and in either case $O$ contains *all* $a_n$. So certainly $a_n \to x$.
We see that limits of sequences need not be unique. Note also that a constant sequence with rational value also converges to all rationals.

Also, if $x \in \mathbb{P}$, then $\mathbb{P}$ is itself an open set containing $x$ that contains *no* points $a_n$. So $a_n \not\to x$.

As a bonus if $b_n = \frac{\pi}{n}$, so all $b_n$ are irrational, then $(b_n)$
converges to all $x \in \mathbb{P}$ and does not converge to any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, in a similar way.

Also, if $c_n$ is defined as $c_{2k} = \frac{1}{2k}, c_{2k+1} = \frac{\pi}{2k+1}$, then $c_n$ converges to no point: no rational point can be a limit as $\mathbb{Q}$ is an open neighbourhood that misses infinitely many $c_n$, and no irrational point can be a limit as the same holds for $\mathbb{P}$.

Reasoning this way we can easily determine the convergence of any sequence. And if any rational is a limit, then all rationals are. Likewise for irrationals.

Comment: Okay this makes perfect sense, thanks. But as a follow up question, in this particular topology we can see that $a_n\longrightarrow p$ in $\mathbb{Q,R}$ but not the case in $\mathbb{I}$. Since we are taking about the topology as a whole and not one particular field, does that mean $a_n$ diverges because $\mathbb{I}\in\tau$?

Comment: @LuisRobles $(a_n)$ converges. Every rational is a limit. A sequence is divergent iff there is no $x$ such that $a_n \to x$. The presence of $\mathbb{I}$ does not change that.